# Arraylist vs Array for finding element?

Tags: java

Which is the most efficient way of finding an element in terms of performance. Say I have 100's of strings. I need to find whether a specified string is available in those bulk strings. I have contains() method in Arraylist, But I need to iterate through Array for the same purpose.  Anyone explain, which is the best way of doing this in terms of performance.

Answer (score 19):

> Say I have 100's of strings. I need to find whether a specified string is available in those bulk strings.

That sounds like you want a [`HashSet<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) - not a list *or* an array. At least, that's the case if the hundreds of strings is the same every time you want to search. If you're searching within a different set of strings every time, you're not going to do better than O(N) if you receive the set in an arbitrary order.

In general, checking for containment in a list/array is an O(N) operation, whereas in a hash-based data structure it's O(1). Of course there's also the cost of performing the hashing and equality checking, but that's a different matter.

Another option would be a sorted list, which would be O(log N).

If you care about the ordering, you might want to consider a [`LinkedHashSet<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), which maintains insertion order but still has O(1) access. (It's basically a linked list combined with a hash set.)

Comment: Or perhaps a `LinkedHashSet` if he needs to maintain a concept of order.

Comment: @arshajii: Was just in the middle of adding that, in fact :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I'll edit that in. Basically I'm assuming the check is against the same set of strings every time.

Answer (score 4):

An `Arraylist` uses an array as backing data so the performance will be the same for both

Answer (score 1):

Look at the implementation of `ArrayList#contains` which calls `indexOf()`

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

You would do the exact same thing if you implemented the `contains()` on your own for an array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about performance issues. It will not affect much. Its good and easy to use `contains()` method in `ArrayList`

Comment: I'd argue O(n) vs a possible O(1) does have a possibly significant impact, depending on context.